# Laravel Models - add non-database field

Tags: php, laravel-5, model

I have a model in Laravel called Checkout. It is just tied to a table in the database called checkouts.

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Checkout extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $table = 'checkouts';
}
```

What I would like to do is add a field to the model that isn't a field in the table. Is this even possible?

If need be, I will completely manually build the model, but I have never seen any examples of that either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Laravel's [`Accessor`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) as:

```
public function getSomeExtraFieldAttribute()
{
    return 2*4; // just for exmaple
}
```

Then you can access it using

```
$checkout = App\Checkout::find(1);

$checkout->some_extra_field;
```

Comment: I am looking at the documentation... the way I understand it, if I create a function in the model called getSomeFieldAttribute, I can call that in the application as some_field (as if it were a field from the database connected to that model)... am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: Yes, you got it r8 and also you can use any attribute of the model inside the `getSomeFieldAttribute()`  function, using `$this` as `$this->id`

Comment: Laravel just keeps getting better. Thanks for your help.